# How can I use a BlobTrigger to bind to CloudBlockBlob in an Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobssdk

I have the following function in my project:

```
[FunctionName("my-func")]
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("data/{name}")] CloudBlockBlob blob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Started Processing: {name}");

    await blob.DeleteAsync();

    log.Info($"Finished Processing: {name}");
}
```

When I attempt to run the function locally using v1.0.4 of the Azure Functions CLI I get this error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'SampleFunction.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind BlobTrigger to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob'.
```

All documentation I have seen for Azure Functions and WebJobs SDK say this is supported.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Blobs#-types-that-you-can-bind-to-blobs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably referencing some NuGet package that has a dependency on non-compatible version of `WindowsAzure.Storage` assembly (version `8.x.x`). If so, be sure to remove it. Unless you are using some additional binding, your `csproj` references should look as simple as this:

```
<ItemGroup>           
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.6" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: That was exactly the issue.  I had other code that required 8.x.x that I removed to simplify the example.  Once I removed the reference everything worked as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeh, that's a known problem with assembly version conflicts and lack of binding redirects. Very confusing, but no proper solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the Azure Storage Emulator:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator> AzureStorageEmulator.exe start
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.2.0.0 command line tool
Autodetect requested. Autodetecting SQL Instance to use.
Looking for a LocalDB Installation.
Probing SQL Instance: '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.
Found a LocalDB Installation.
Probing SQL Instance: '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.
Found SQL Instance (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB.
Creating database AzureStorageEmulatorDb52 on SQL instance '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.
```

Comment: He's probably just connecting to Azure Storage. Connectivity issue will give another error.