# Using WindowsAzure.Storage 8.5 with CloudBlockBlob and BlobAttribute in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

While using WindowsAzure.Storage 7.2.1 one function is fine, but other functions depend on 8.5 and they fail.
If I'm using WindowsAzure.Storage 8.5 to upload blob file it throws an error:

```
Can't bind Blob to type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob
```

**How would you resolve such conflict?**

Here is my code to upload a blob:

```
public static void Run(other params, IBinder binder)
{
        string fileUrl = $"test-blob/{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";                   
        var blob = binder.Bind<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob>(new BlobAttribute(fileUrl));
        blob.UploadText($"test text file: {fileUrl}");
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940492/how-can-i-use-a-blobtrigger-to-bind-to-cloudblockblob-in-an-azure-function

Comment: when I remove dependency other function throws: "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.5.0.0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use any version of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` higher than the one used by Functions runtime (`7.2.1` for `1.x` versions of Functions). Remove that reference from your project.

For further information see [Binding redirect support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/992).

Comment: Functions V2 is now in general availability and provides much more flexibility in this area.